# web3 not working because of some deprecated library

Tags: solidity, web3js, web3-providers

May be this is some stupid question to ask but I'm absolute beginner. Guide me what changes I need to do. Thank you.

```
    App = {
  web3Provider: null,
  contracts: {},
  account: '0x0',
  hasVoted: false,

  init: function() {
    return App.initWeb3();
  },

  initWeb3: function() {
    // TODO: refactor conditional
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
      // If a web3 instance is already provided by Meta Mask.
      App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
      web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
      // Specify default instance if no web3 instance provided
      App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545');
      web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);
    }
    return App.initContract();
  },

  initContract: function() {
    $.getJSON("Election.json", function(election) {
      // Instantiate a new truffle contract from the artifact
      App.contracts.Election = TruffleContract(election);
      // Connect provider to interact with contract
      App.contracts.Election.setProvider(App.web3Provider);

      App.listenForEvents();

      return App.render();
    });
  },

  // Listen for events emitted from the contract
  listenForEvents: function() {
    App.contracts.Election.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      // Restart Chrome if you are unable to receive this event
      // This is a known issue with Metamask
      // https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/2393
      instance.votedEvent({}, {
        fromBlock: 0,
        toBlock: 'latest'
      }).watch(function(error, event) {
        console.log("event triggered", event)
        // Reload when a new vote is recorded
        App.render();
      });
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    var electionInstance;
    var loader = $("#loader");
    var content = $("#content");

    loader.show();
    content.hide();

    // Load account data
    web3.eth.getCoinbase(function(err, account) {
      if (err === null) {
        App.account = account;
        $("#accountAddress").html("Your Account: " + account);
      }
    });

    // Load contract data
    App.contracts.Election.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      electionInstance = instance;
      return electionInstance.candidatesCount();
    }).then(function(candidatesCount) {
      var candidatesResults = $("#candidatesResults");
      candidatesResults.empty();

      var candidatesSelect = $('#candidatesSelect');
      candidatesSelect.empty();

      for (var i = 1; i <= candidatesCount; i++) {
        electionInstance.candidates(i).then(function(candidate) {
          var id = candidate[0];
          var name = candidate[1];
          var voteCount = candidate[2];

          // Render candidate Result
          var candidateTemplate = "<tr><th>" + id + "</th><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + voteCount + "</td></tr>"
          candidatesResults.append(candidateTemplate);

          // Render candidate ballot option
          var candidateOption = "<option value='" + id + "' >" + name + "</ option>"
          candidatesSelect.append(candidateOption);
        });
      }
      return electionInstance.voters(App.account);
    }).then(function(hasVoted) {
      // Do not allow a user to vote
      if(hasVoted) {
        $('form').hide();
      }
      loader.hide();
      content.show();
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.warn(error);
    });
  },

  castVote: function() {
    var candidateId = $('#candidatesSelect').val();
    App.contracts.Election.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      return instance.vote(candidateId, { from: App.account });
    }).then(function(result) {
      // Wait for votes to update
      $("#content").hide();
      $("#loader").show();
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
  }
};

$(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {
    App.init();
  });
});
```

**Warnings & Errors showing in browser:**

1.

> You are accessing the MetaMask window.web3.currentProvider shim. This
> property is deprecated; use window.ethereum instead. For details, see:
> https://docs.metamask.io/guide/provider-migration.html#replacing-window-web3
> get @ inpage.js:1

2. 

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: instance.votedEvent is not a function at app.js:44

3. 

> app.js:106 TypeError: electionInstance.voters is not a function
> at app.js:97 (anonymous) @ app.js:106

Comment: Perhaps it's better if you find a more recent tutorial?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Comment: @Angel Yes. The problem was not with the code but the deprecated libraries. I was following tutorial of Dapp University. After weeks of research now all the errors are fixed.

Comment: Can you share the solution code @Sudipta Basak

Comment: [DeVote](https://github.com/sudiptab2100/DeVote) check my github repo. @MothishwaraNavinkumarN